# How do I save the user submitted values of a multi-step node editing form in the database after last step submission?

Tags: 7, forms

In Drupal 7, I am trying to programmatically create a custom content type. I have defined my custom content type implementing [`hook_node_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_info/7).

For my node editing form, I am using [`hook_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_form/7) and defined my custom node's title here. I used `hook_form_alter()` to convert my node editing form into a multi-step form, where I used the following code.

```
if ($step == 4) {
  $form['actions']['finish'] = array(
    '#type'   => 'submit',
    #value'  => t('Submit'),
  );
}
// Add validation handler.
$form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_form_validate';
// Add submission handler.
$form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_form_submit';   

function mymodule_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message(t('validating multistep form'));
}

function mymodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  switch($form_state['triggering_element']['#value']) {
    case $form['actions']['next']['#value']: // if 'Continue >>' is clicked.
      $step++;
      $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
      break;
    case $form['actions']['finish']['#value']: // if 'Submit' is clicked.
      $form_state['rebuild'] = FALSE;
      // To Do.
      // Store the values from the form in the database here.
      drupal_set_message(t('Your form has been submitted'));
      break;
  }
}
```

My multi-step form is working great, but I am stuck on my last step of the form, where I save the user submitted values in the database. I am not getting any reference on this topic.
I am looking for information on how to save my this node in the database, what hooks to use, and some more details. Please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

After you have constructed your custom node object by stepping through your multi-form, use the [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/7) function. That will write your node to the database.

To see how Drupal creates and saves it nodes you can take a look at [node_add()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.pages.inc/function/node_add/7). Hope that helps a little.